# I need help with a rather basic integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Usually we integrate $\sec^3(x)$ with the “integration by parts” method. However, in my opinion $\sec^3(x)$ can be broken into $\sec^2(x)$ and $\sec(x)$. From then onwards, we can use the trigonometric identity $1+\tan^2(x)=\sec^2(x)$. However, doing so just cancels everything on the left and right hand side which does prove that left and right hand side are equal but doesn't lead me to the traditional solution of $\sec^3(x)$ (which is achieved through integration by parts). By left and right hand side I mean everything ends up getting cancelled out, which yields a 0 on both sides.

My question is that why isn't my method valid, although it's technically correct.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to guess what you're discussing, for example what do you mean by left side and right side?

Comment: Please write in Latex.

Comment: I'm not clear on how what you want to differs from what you say we usually do. It sounds like you're trying to make [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed#Integration_by_parts) work. The integral $\int\sec^3xdx$ gets expressed in terms of itself, but a rearrangement fixes that. Or did you have a different calculation in mind? If so, please edit it into the question. (I wonder if you want to exploit $\sec^3x=\sec x+\sec x\tan^2x$, which ultimately requires the same rearrangement.)

Answer (score 1):

For the integration of odd powers of $\sec(x)$ you may also use the following trick:

$$ \text{For any }T\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\qquad\int_{0}^{T}\frac{d\theta}{\cos^3\theta} = \int_{0}^{T}\frac{\cos\theta}{(1-\sin^2\theta)^2} = \int_{0}^{\sin T}\frac{du}{(1-u^2)^2}$$
while for the integration of even powers

$$ \text{For any }T\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\qquad\int_{0}^{T}\frac{d\theta}{\cos^4\theta} = \int_{0}^{\tan T}\frac{dt}{(1+t^2)\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)^2}$$
and in both cases you have reduced the problem to the integration of a rational function.

Answer (score 0):

You may continue your approach as follows
\begin{align}
\int \sec^3x\ dx=& \int \tan^2x \sec x +\sec x \ dx\\
=& \int \frac12( \tan^2x +\sec^2x)\sec x + \frac12( \tan^2x -\sec^2x)\sec x\ +\sec x \ dx\\
=& \ \frac12\int ( \tan^2x +\sec^2x)\sec x \ dx +\frac12\int \sec x\ dx\\
=&\ \frac12 \tan x\sec x+\frac12\ln (\sec x+\tan x)+C
\end{align}